# Creating a Category Page with Thumbnails and Captions Underneath.....<figure> or <aside>

Tags: html, css, figure, caption

I have a page that I am trying to create that looks like the image attached.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
I got so far as putting in the thumbnails because no matter what I do, the thumbnails will line up like I write the code to do, however once I get the text links under them, it goes out of whack.

I tried using the '

This is what I got so far:

```
`<div id="ProductsBodyThmbs">
 <figure><img src="images/productThmb.jpg" alt="Product Thumbnails"></figure>
 <figcaption>Text Link 1</figcaption>
 <figure><img src="images/productThmb.jpg" alt="Product Thumbnails"></figure>
 <figcaption>Text Link 2</figcaption>
 <figure><img src="images/productThmb.jpg" alt="Product Thumbnails"></figure>
 <figcaption>Text Link 3</figcaption>
 <figure><img src="images/productThmb.jpg" alt="Product Thumbnails"></figure>
 <figcaption>Text Link 4</figcaption>
 <figure><img src="images/productThmb.jpg" alt="Product Thumbnails"></figure>
 <figcaption>Text Link 5</figcaption></div>`
```

Then the CSS I have for that div and tags goes like this:

```
#ProductsBodyThmbs {
float: left;
width: 640px;
}

figure {
width: 80px;    
float: left;
}
```

Any help or advise on this would be a great help...

Comment: ok, I figured out what I was doing. Basically, I was closing <figure> BEFORE adding the <figcaption> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out what I was doing. Basically, I was closing `<figure>` **BEFORE** adding the `<figcaption>` tag. so basically here is the soultion below. I included the `<figcaption>` **INSIDE** the `<figure>` tag and now it all works as   expected.

```
<div class="ProductThmbsLeft">
<figure>
<img src="images/productThmb.jpg" alt="Product Thumbnails">              
<figcaption><a href="#">text text</a></figcaption></figure>
<figure>
<img src="images/productThmb.jpg" alt="Product Thumbnails">
<figcaption><a href="#">text text</a></figcaption></figure>
<figure>
<img src="images/productThmb.jpg" alt="Product Thumbnails">
<figcaption><a href="#">text text</a></figcaption></figure>
<figure>
<img src="images/productThmb.jpg" alt="Product humbnails">
<figcaption><a href="#">text text</a></figcaption></figure>
</div>
```